# How to allow users to delete objects in S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-amplify

I have a mobile app which has users authenticate via AWS Cognito and they end up in a user pool. They're able to put objects into the bucket no problem, but they cant delete. What i want to do is for each logged in user to be able to delete an file in the bucket.

The path to the files is for example: `my_bucket_name/protected/eu-west-2:de55c2rf-8f1e-836d-88f9-82da662aau6dt/videos/video1`

To delete, i call this:

```
import { Storage } from 'aws-amplify';
```

.
.
.

```
delFromS3 = async () => {
      Storage.remove('protected/eu-west-2:de55c2rf-8f1e-836d-88f9-82da662aau6dt/videos/video1')  
         .then(result => console.log('Deleted Video from S3'))
         .catch(err => console.log('Deleting video from S3 error: ', err));
  }
```

I kept receiving the error Access Denied when calling this, so i added a Bucket Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:DeleteObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket_name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The only time this function returns a result is when i put `"Principal": "*"` but this makes my bucket PUBLIC to anyone, which i don't want to do. It also doesn't accept this as a valid Prinipal policy:

```
"Principal": { "AWS": [ "arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-2:968257789397:userpool/eu-west-2_2ecGAT74q" ] }.
```

So i need to know what the correct Principal is.

So i either need a way to allow users in the cognito user pool to be authorised to delete an object. Or because i manually know the path to the file in each users sub-bucket (e.g. `/protected/eu-west-2:de55c2rf-8f1e-836d-88f9-82da662aau6dt/videos/video1`) just pass that in my `delFromS3()` function. What should my bucket policy read? Anything else i'm missing here?

Please help!

Comment: Have you read about `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}` (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html)?

Comment: Yes i tried adding that like so: "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket_name/protected/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*" but it still didnt work

Comment: Do you have a api back end

Comment: I use AWS Amplify, just to instantiate DynamoDB and Cognito but thats about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an IAM user for actions such as DELETE and use your cognito id for access only. For an IAM user, your Principal would look like this:

```
"Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::841367581918:user/your-iam-name"
},
```

You would provide the accessKey for this user at the top of your api file like so:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
s3.config.update({
    region: process.env.BUCKET_REGION,
    accessKeyId: process.env.IAM_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.IAM_SECRET_KEY
});
```

Then, to delete your object:

```
deleteObject: async (req, res) => {

    const bucket = process.env.YOUR_BUCKET;

    try {
        // delete record in DB
        //....
        let cognitoId = req.user.cognitoId;
        let key = cognitoId + '/' + path; // my folder name is user's cognitoId and path is the rest of url.

        const params = {
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key: key
        }

        try {
            await s3.headObject(params).promise();
            console.log("File found");
            try {
                await s3.deleteObject(params).promise();
                console.log("deleted successfully");
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                res.status(500).send(error.message);
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.status(500).send(error.message);
        }
        res.status(200).send("success");
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: So i'm using import { Storage } from 'aws-amplify' not AWS.S3 which makes the code different somewhat. This works successfully to Storage.Put(). There could be potentially thousands of IAM users everytime they first sign in via Cognito. To have an accessKey sounds overkill for each user. I know the arn for my userpool but when i tried:  "Principal": { "AWS": [ "arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-2:968257789397:userpool/eu-west-2_2ecGAT74q" ] } it still doesn't work in my bucket policy. Am i missing something?

Comment: @chai86 It's not an access key for each user, it's an access key for your api. Your user authenticates with your api and your api performs the operation on the user's behalf.

Answer (score 0):

Amplify CLI will help you provision the correct S3 bucket policies against the "public", "protected", and "private" folder. https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/storage#restrict-access To accomplish what you want to do, you can

1. Using Amplify.Storage, upload with `accessLevel: .protected` which will upload the object to S3 under `<bucket>/protected/<key>`
2. Download using the same accessLevel to retrieve at `<bucket>/protected/<key>`

```
let options = StorageDownloadDataRequest.Options(accessLevel: .protected)
Amplify.Storage.downloadData(key: "myKey", options: options) { (event) in
    ...
}
```

Essentially Amplify Storage plugin is prepending the storage access level in front of the key for you. When no accessLevel is specified in the call, it will prepend "public" by default.

You can find a related blog post here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/introducing-aws-amplify-for-ios-and-android/

corresponding sample app: https://github.com/nikhil-dabhade/amplify-ios-samples/tree/master/samples/ios/amplify/storage/AmplifyStorageSampleApp